# How to call overridden (parent) class function in R?

Tags: r

I'm using `geepack`'s `geeglm` to fit a model, which inherits from `geeglm`, `gee`, `glm`, and `lm`. The package defines a simple default [`plot.geeglm`](https://rdrr.io/cran/geepack/src/R/geeglm.R#sym-plot.geeglm) for `geeglm`, which can obviously be used like `plot(geeglm(...))`. However, I'd like to call the base [`plot.lm`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/plot.lm), which I think should work because `geeglm` inherits from `lm`?

1. Is my understanding of how inheritance *should* work correct? -- I figure sometimes this approach will break, but I don't know how to even call `plot.lm` on a `geeglm` object.
2. How do I call an overridden class function for an inherited class? -- I figure this would apply to other class functions too ...

### MWE

```R
library(geepack)
A = data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rbinom(100,1,.5),id=rbinom(100,1,.2))
g = geeglm(y~x,data=A,id=A$id)
plot(g)
# plot.lm(g) # -> Error in plot.lm(g) : could not find function "plot.lm"
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try `plot(lm(g))`

Comment: Thanks! This works. Though this seems to cast the whole object before plotting? Still curious if there is another way to call `plot.lm` directly on `g`.

Comment: you can call `plot.lm` using `stats:::plot.lm` but `stats:::plot.lm(g)` doesn't work, presumably because other functions that `plot.lm` relies on act differently for `geeglm` objects than for `lm` objects.  Also there is no guarantee that my comment above does anything sensible, I'm assuming that `lm(g)` turns g into an lm object in some kind of sensible way

Comment: a bit more investigation suggests you should be careful about exactly which residuals are being plotted here.